# If don’t allow user to update document in firestore then it will also not allow set with merge?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating document for every user when they sign up(using firebase Authentication ) using cloud function after that i do not want that user can set with merge any extra field in this document but user can update existing field.How can i do this?

set(
  {a: {b: {c: true}}},
  {merge: true}
)

Comment: Do you have some code you could possibly show of what you have tried so far? This can help others diagnose your issue and get you to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to "validate your schema" with Firestore Security Rules.

Watch this video from the Firebase Summit 2018 and in particular Tip #3: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvLkkLjHdkw&t=9m02s

So following the video, you would do something like:

```
 ......
 allow update: if request.resource.data.size() == 3
               && request.resource.data.project is string
               && request.resource.data.project.size() > 1
               && request.resource.data.project.size() < 64
               && request.resource.data.userName is string
               && request.resource.data.userPreferredColor is string  
 ....
```